# Qt - Add item from a second window to ListWidget in MainWindow

Tags: c++, list, qt, qlistwidget, qlist

I have a QDialog where I can enter a Text and add it to a ListWidget inside the MainWindow after I clicked OK. Therefore I created a Method in the MainWindow class AddMessageToList(message) where the entered message is added to the ListWidget. I call the Method inside my ListAdder class (2nd Window). However nothing gets added to the ListWidget.

Here are the codes:

listadder.cpp

```cpp
#include "listadder.h"
#include "ui_listadder.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

ListAdder::ListAdder(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::ListAdder)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

ListAdder::~ListAdder()
{
    delete ui;
}

void ListAdder::on_buttonBox_accepted()
{
    MainWindow mw;
    QString message = ui->lnText->text();
    mw.AddMessageToList(message);
}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "listadder.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_pbt_Edit_clicked()
{
    ListAdder lsadd;
    lsadd.exec();
}

void MainWindow::AddMessageToList(QString message)
{
    ui->lsItems->addItem(message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it!

I created a QString method GetMessage() where I return the entered text. In the MainWindow I call the method and add the text to the ListWidget.

listadder.cpp:

```cpp
#include "listadder.h"
#include "ui_listadder.h"
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

ListAdder::ListAdder(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::ListAdder)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

ListAdder::~ListAdder()
{
    delete ui;
}

QString ListAdder::GetMessage()
{
    QString message = ui->lnText->text();
    return message;
}

void ListAdder::on_buttonBox_accepted()
{
    
}
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "listadder.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_pbt_Edit_clicked()
{
    ListAdder lsadd;
    lsadd.exec();
    ui->lsItems->addItem(lsadd.GetMessage());
}
```

Comment: Of course, it's up to you, how to get the goal. Meanwhile, why don't you use `QInputDialog::getText` to get a string from the user? Please, refer to https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qinputdialog.html#getText